# Show point value in chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, series

I have this chart and it works fine, but how can I show the value of orange line on Y axis (this line always has the same value) with C# code?.
I want to show the blue label.

The orange series is called "Fido" and its value is -15000.

I update the image

[image]

Comment: How do you do it for the red and green points? Is it not the same?

Comment: Which UI technology is this? And which charting technology?

Comment: Win Forms, but i want only one value of Y axis before -50000

Comment: which property I must change to view  "-€ 15.000,00" on YAxis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how that control works or if it has some special way of doing it.

However, You can listen to the OnPaint Event of that graph control and draw to e.graphics the string on that position.

Comment: I suggest you answer the question and mark your answer as the correct one, The site highly depends on being able to look at other's solutions..